# Restore last state of activity (dialog ) in android on resume & restart

Tags: android, dialog, android-lifecycle

My dialog gets open and ask for code but when user switches to message box of mobile phone to see the code by minimizing the app.Then after resumes the app the dialog box disappears.
 My app is unable to restore last UI State.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Enter Your Registeration Code");
alert.setMessage("Registeration code has been delivered on your registered number via sms");
// Set an EditText view to get user input
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setCancelable(false);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
        String regsCode2 = etFake.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.compareToIgnoreCase(regsCode2) == 0) {
            validCodeMatch = objCommonServices.sendEvalidCode(String.valueOf(mobileNo), password, "OK", regsCode2);
            if (validCodeMatch.contains("Code Match")) {
                showDialog(2);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                removeDialog(3);
                showDialog(3);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to add logic to [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) to keep track of the state of your application.

Comment: Kindly give example to add logic to onPause and onResume to keep trackof the state of theapplication

Comment: You can find all the relative information on the site referenced by the provided links. I suggest you look there first for information and try for yourself.

Comment: How do you show a dialog? Use showDialog() or DialogFragment.